# Maintaining state of fragment or elements even when navigating away from the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a counterdown timer for my match time in a game that is within my match fragment;

```
//Countdown clock button
    Button counterBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
    counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            updateDBMatches("played", 1);
            final Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
            new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    stopWatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    counterBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    long l = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                    int i = (int) l;
                    counterBtn.setText(secondsToString(i));
                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.airhornsoundeffect);
                    mp.start();
                    //Disable score buttons
                    Button homeFoulsBtnDisabled = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFouls);
                    Button awayFoulsBtnDisabled = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayFouls);
                    homeFoulsBtnDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                    awayFoulsBtnDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                    Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                    stopWatch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    counterBtn.setText("FULL TIME");
                    updateDBMatches("played", 2);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

All works great, until someone navigates to another fragment and I get errors once the countdown has completed. So for example the MediaPlayer mp when it tries to play the sound throws a null exception.

Is there a way to maintain state of a fragment even if the user navigates to another one?

All help appreciated.

Comment: post error log cat

Comment: Do you want to play the sound even when the user is in another fragment? If not then release the countdown timer once the fragment is destroyed. Your app crashes because it is trying to find the views inside `onFinish()` method of the countdown timer

Comment: Yes, I'd like to maintain the state of the counter counting down and also the sound at the end.